# Perl Issue with concurrent requests with IO::Async and Future::Utils

Tags: perl, asynchronous, future

I'm trying to use an IO loop to send concurrent requests (5) to a pool of hosts (3), but the code stops after 3 requests. I've had help to kickstart this code, but I certainly understand most of it now. What I don't get is why the number of processed requests is linked to the number of hosts in my pool of hosts. The objective of the code is to determine routing information from a given IP.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;
use IO::Async::Loop;
use Future::Utils 'fmap_concat';

my @hosts = qw(host1 host2 host3);
my @ssh;
my $user = 'myuser';
my $pass = 'mypassword';

foreach my $host (@hosts) {
  my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(host => $host, user => $user, password => $pass, master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"]);
  die "Failed to connect to $host: " . $ssh->error if $ssh->error;
  push @ssh, $ssh;
}

my @ipv4 = (
  'ip1','ip2','ip3','ip4','ip5'
);

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;

my $future = fmap_concat {
  my $ip = shift;
  my $ssh = shift @ssh;
  my $cmd = 'show ip route '.$ip.' | i \*';
  my @remote_cmd = $ssh->make_remote_command($cmd);
  return $loop->run_process(command => \@remote_cmd)
    ->transform(done => sub { [@_] })
    ->on_ready(sub { push @ssh, $ssh });
} generate => sub { return () unless @ssh and @ipv4; shift @ipv4 }, concurrent => scalar @ssh;

my @results = $future->get;

foreach my $result (@results) {
  my ($exit, $stdout) = @$result;
  print $stdout, "\n";
}
```

Here are the results

```
Connection to host1 closed by remote host.
Connection to host2 closed by remote host.
Connection to host3 closed by remote host.
 * ip1, from host1, 3w0d ago, via GigabitEthernet0/0/0

 * ip2, from host2, 7w0d ago, via GigabitEthernet0/0/0

 * ip3, from host3, 3w0d ago, via GigabitEthernet0/0/1
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem, I am even trying random sleeps to alter the timing of futures returning but it always schedules the last two once spots free up... You are using the latest version of Future::Utils?

Comment: Something to try in case there's a weird ordering issue: replace the `on_ready` handler with `->followed_by(sub { my $f = shift; push @ssh, $ssh; return $f });` - This will sequence a new future (and use the same future for its result), so it will ensure the `$ssh` is pushed back onto the array before the future sequence is ready.

Comment: I've just updated Future::Utils from 0.42 -> 0.43 but the condition remains

Comment: I tried replacing on_ready with followed_by , but the behavior is the same

Comment: Maybe try some debugging as mentioned in https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#DEBUGGING, the three connections getting closed by the remote is suspicious.

Comment: It looks like there was a race condition with the ssh connection not being released properly when the future was being invoked on the $host again.

undef $ssh fixed it 

` ->on_ready(sub { undef $ssh; push @hosts, $host ; }); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching on the problem, I found out that network devices such as Cisco might have an issue handling several requests over the same connection. So the code changed a bit in a way where a new connection is opened everytime the future is called instead of using a pool of pre-opened connections.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::OpenSSH;
use IO::Async::Loop;
use Future::Utils 'fmap_concat';

my @hosts = qw(host1 host2 host3);
my @ssh;
my $user = 'myuser';
my $pass = 'mypassword';

my @ipv4 = (
  'ip1','ip2','ip3','ip4','ip5'
);

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;

my $future = fmap_concat {
  my $ip = shift;
  my $host = shift @hosts;
  my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(host => $host, user => $user, password => $pass, master_opts => [-o => "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"]);
    die "Failed to connect to $host: " . $ssh->error if $ssh->error;
  my $cmd = 'show ip route '.$ip.' | i \*|^Routing entry';
  my @remote_cmd = $ssh->make_remote_command($cmd);
  return $loop->run_process(command => \@remote_cmd)
  ->transform(done => sub { [@_] })
  ->on_ready(sub { push @hosts, $host ; });
} generate => sub { return () unless @hosts and @ipv4; shift @ipv4 }, concurrent => scalar @hosts;

my @results = $future->get;

foreach my $result (@results) {
  my ($exit, $stdout) = @$result;
  print $stdout, "\n";
}
```

But this has leaded to other problems with underlying openssh library. 
It looks like there was a race condition with the ssh connection not being released properly when the future was being invoked on the $host again. 
undef $ssh fixed it

```
->on_ready(sub { undef $ssh; push @hosts, $host ; });
```

Comment: I think you skipped the context (mentioned on IRC) that you are now opening a new SSH connection for each command.

Comment: thanks @Grinnz I've edited the post to reflect our discussions